# Regex no match when returning a row from Filemaker via pyodbc python

Tags: python, pyodbc, filemaker

Im having an issue where I have a sting and want to match 6 digits in a row. If I define the string manually and run re.match() I get a match.

I want to match the string when I return a row from Filemaker via pyodbc. even though the returned string is the same as the one i defined there is no match.

```
string = 'A99_OL_IT123456_SD_003.jpg'
x = re.findall(r'\d{6}', string)
print(x[0])
```

prints 123456 which is what I'm after. But I want to get this info form the database.

```
sql = cur.execute("""SELECT fileName FROM UpdateE WHERE fileName = 'A99_PL_IT123456_SD_003.jpg'""")
row = cur.fetchone()
fn = str(row[0])
print(fn) ### Prints the filename correctly
item = re.findall(r'\d{6}', fn)
print(item) ### No Match
```

The type of 'fn' is a string, and the field it is getting it from in filemaker is formatted at Text.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Richard

Comment: What does `print(repr(fn))` show?

Comment: it prints: ''A\x009\x009\x00_\x00P\x00L\x00_\x00I\x00T\x001\x002\x003\x004\x005\x006\x00_\x00S\x00D\x00_\x000\x000\x003\x00.\x00j\x00p\x00g\x00'' so i added fn.replace('\x00','') and it worked! Thanks so much!!